# Solution of Linear Diophantine Equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, constraints, linear-diophantine-equations

How to find all solutions of Linear Diophantine Equation $a \cdot x + b \cdot y = c $ given $a,b,c$ where $c$ is divisible by $\gcd(a,b)$ and constraints are $x_0 \leq x \leq x_1$ and $y_0 \leq y \leq y_1$ ?

Comment: Solution set of $(x,y,c)$ is every $x,y$ within the constraint, since every linear combination of $a,b$ is divisible by their GCD.

Comment: @LKM. Given a = 1, b = c = 2, and 0 <= x,y <= 1000, how many integers x,y have x + 2y = 2???

Comment: Then of course there is 2 solutions, namely, $(x,y)=(0,1), (2,0)$. So the question should be formulated as follows? \\  How to find all solutions (x,y) of Linear Diophantine Equation $a \cdot x + b \cdot y = c$ with $a,b,c$ fixed and c divisible by $\gcd(a,b)$ ?

Comment: Edited the question.